# Issue trying to make a color flipper with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Thisis my first JS project and i cant figure out where i went wrong, i am trying to make a color flipper whre if you click a button it picks a random color from an array of colors and make that the background color.

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];

const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {

  const randomItem = colors[getRandomItem];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomItem;
  color.textContent = randomItem;

});

const getRandomItem = function () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <nav>
        <div class="nav-center">
            <h4>color flipper</h4>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="index.html">simple</a></li>
                <li><a href="hex.html">hex</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
            <button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
```

Comment: You are not calling `getRandomItem`. `colors[getRandomItem];` should be `colors[getRandomItem()];` (In general with a problem like this a simple `console.log` of key variables will quickly reveal the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```js
const randomItem = colors[getRandomItem];
```

you aren't calling the function. Put parentheses after you write its name: `getRandomItem()`.

**Snippet**

```js
const colors = ["green", "red", "rgba(133,122,200)", "#f15025"];

const button = document.getElementById("btn");
const color = document.querySelector(".color");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {

  const randomItem = colors[getRandomItem()];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomItem;
  color.textContent = randomItem;

});

const getRandomItem = function () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- javascript -->

    <nav>
        <div class="nav-center">
            <h4>color flipper</h4>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="index.html">simple</a></li>
                <li><a href="hex.html">hex</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>background color : <span class="color">#f1f5f8</span></h2>
            <button class="btn btn-hero" id="btn">click me</button>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
```